# How do I edit to fit with all browsers?

Tags: css

[image: image demonstrate the problem]

I have a problem that the site appears differently on more than resolution.

```css
/* CSS Document */

a{
 text-decoration:none;
}

body{
 background-color:#F2F2F2;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetice, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 margin:0 auto;
 line-height:1.5;
 width:100%
}
#body{
 width:90%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
#wrap{
 height:auto;
}

.logo{
 margin-left:2%;
 margin-top:5%;
 float:left;
 width:auto;
}

.kuka{
 margin-left:39.5%;
 width:auto;
}

#nav{
 background-color:#3394e1;
 color:#FFF;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #00377c;
 width:90%;
}

#nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0 auto;
}


#nav ul li{
 display:inline;
}

#nav a:link, .siteheader  a:visited {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:1.4% 0.3%;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:12px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

#nav a:hover, .siteheader  a:active,
#nav .active a:link .siteheader .active a:visited {
 background-color:#FFF;
 color:#000;
 text-shadow:none;
}

#nav ul li a {
 position:relative;
 color:#FFF;
}
```

I do not think the problem is in the CSS,
I think the problem is easy, but I can not solve it.

html code

```html
<div id="wrap">
         <div id="header">
             <div class="logo">
                 <img src="image/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="230" height="105">
                </div>
                <div class="kuka">
                 <img src="image/Website-Banner-final.png" alt="kuka" width="736" height="190">
                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                 <ul class="nav">
                     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="company_profile.html">Company Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href="about_robotics.html">About Robotics</a></li>
               <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
              <li><a href="automation.html">Automation</a></li>
              <li><a href="used_machines.html">Used Machines</a></li>
              <li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li><a href="technical_support.html">Technical Support</a></li>
              <li><a href="send_an_enquiry.html">Send An Enquiry</a></li>
              <li><a href="join_our_team.html">Join Our Team</a></li>
               <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
               <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
      </div>
```

i hope the problem be explained

Comment: You should share your HTML too. Use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: there's no image - you should create an **[example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** of the issue you are experiencing - different browsers render elements different, you should use a framework that includes or include yourself a **[normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)** and or a **[reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**

Comment: Please elaborate a little on what goes wrong and what you expect. Also, to fix your site we would probably need your HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Viewport width and height for With & Height. Like width: ##vw;

Comment: i can't understand what illustration Can clarification in code

Comment: From My point of view it is happening because you are defining the Width of image with a fixed value.